# Deserialize JSON using Newtonsoft.Json's JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonString)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I was been working with an extension method using generics and Newtonsoft.Json's `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TSource>(jsonString)`

the serialization works as expected

```
string value = string.Empty;
value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(null);      //"null"
value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("null");    //"null"
value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("value");   //"value"
value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("");        //""
```

But when trying to Deserialize

```
string result = string.Empty;
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("null"); //null, ok
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("value"); //throwing error, expecting "value"
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(""); //throwing error, expecting string.empty
```

> Error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: v. Path '', line 0, position 0.

now I'm used where `TSource : new ()` on the extension method, so that any string return types would be restricted as

```
public static TSource ExecuteScriptForData(this IJavaScriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor, string script, params object[] args) where TSource : new ()
```

which is not letting me to use interfaces like `IList`, `IPerson` or `ReadOnlyCollection` on `TSource`

Now Is there any way to configure the Deserializer so that it would be able to Deserialize strings as Serializer is producing ?

Comment: What your trying to deserialize is not valid json. If it's just a simple string why not store it as is. Maybe it's just me but I don't see the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Nasreddine Yes they are not valid json, but result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("null"); was working, so i was thinking there could be some way. and if as you pointed, shouldn't the serialize would throw error too !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now Is there any way to configure the Deserializer so that it would be able to deserialize strings as Serializer is producing ?

You can use *JsonSerializerSettings*'s *TypeNameHandling* property.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };

var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(null,settings); 
var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, settings);

str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("value", settings);
var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, settings);

str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("", settings);
var obj3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, settings);
```

Comment: this and little if/else made things moving as expecting ... thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

`value` in json does not have any meanings. If you expect your result to be the value of string you have to put it in qoutes:

```
string result = string.Empty;
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("null"); //null, ok
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("'value'"); // "value"
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("''"); // string.Empty
```

Comment: that is interesting, most proply var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }; is doing that one as @EZI